# Asp Net MVC - Membership full update or Controller checking for better performance?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

Mates, to update an user profile, if the user wants to update just a single detail, lets say an email in my controller I am doing this:

```
try
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

            user.Email = model.Email;
            user.IsApproved = model.Active;
            user.ChangePassword(model.Password, model.ConfirmPassword);

            string password = user.GetPassword();
            user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(password, model.SecretQuestion, model.SecretQuestionPassword);

            Membership.UpdateUser(user);

            return Content("Usuário Atualizado com Sucesso!");

        }
```

The question is:
Do I need to put some If conditions to check if other values is set, by cheking if the field is not disabled so I can change only the required collumn or it´s ok to perform a complete update as I have all the field with the values returned from database with its values?

I want a solution with a good performance and I don´t know if would be better to check all the fields or perform a complete update.

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about performance in such a use case is a waste of time. Will your users massively update their emails, say... 1000 times a second? This is one of the features used almost never.

Think about good design. Make meaningful methods. Optimize later, only if you have performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to update only email then only set email. All other fields are loaded from database so they would retain their values. This would also be performance friendly assigned Ming you are using some kind of ORM behind the scenes. Because the SQL generated by the ORM would be succinct.